# Why doesn't such a simple thing as updating the bootstrabtable view work?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

I have a problem with bootstraptable. I cannot update the table view. The simplest example. after selecting **B1**, the table is supplied with data from the **myData1** variable, however, after selecting **B2**, it is not updated with data from the **myData2** variable. What method to use to power the table again on subsequent calls?

```
    <div class="toolbar">
        <button id="B1" class="btn btn-secondary">B1</button>
    </div>
  
    <div class="toolbar">
        <button id="B2" class="btn btn-secondary">B2</button>
    </div>

    <table id="list" class="bootstrap-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="Name">Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>


     var mydata1 = [ {"Name": "Federico"},{"Name": "Madamee"}];
     var mydata2 = [ {"Name": "Susane"},{"Name": "John"}];
    
     $('#B1').click(function () {
     $('#table').bootstrapTable({ data: mydata1 })
      });
    
     $('#B2').click(function () {
     $('#table').bootstrapTable({ data: mydata2 })
      });
```

Comment: of course the table has id ="table"

Answer (score 0):

Bottstrap-table must be have parameter `data-toggle="list"` and completing the table used  `$('#table').bootstrapTable('load',mydata)` or
`$('#table').bootstrapTable('load',mydata2)` then it works:-)